# How is the size of the circuit derived, in proving the threshold theorem?

Tags: nielsen-and-chuang, fault-tolerance

In chapter 10.6.1 in [Nielsen and Chuang](https://csis.pace.edu/%7Ectappert/cs837-19spring/QC-textbook.pdf), the section on concatenated codes and the threshold theorem (pages 480-481) states:

> The size of the simulating circuit goes as $d^k$ times the size of the
> original circuit, where $d$ is a constant representing the maximum number of operations
> used in a fault-tolerant procedure to do an encoded gate and error correction.

It is further explained that if we wish to achieve a final accuracy of $\epsilon$, we are required to concatenate the simulating circuit $k$ times such that:

> $$
> \frac{(cp)^{2^k}}{c} \leq \frac{\epsilon}{p(n)} \tag{10.113}
> $$

where $p(n)$ is the number of gates in the simulating circuit and $\frac{(cp)^{2^k}}{c}$ is the failure probability for a procedure at the highest level.

After this, the size of the circuit is to achieve this accuracy is then given as:

> $$
> d^k = \left(\frac{\log{(p(n)/c\epsilon)}}{\log(1/pc)}\right)^{\log{d}} \tag{10.114}
> $$

My question is, how is the size of the circuit derived in Eq(10.114)? It is closely related to Eq(10.113) after some rearranging, but I cannot see exactly how to get Eq(10.114).

Comment: All the logarithms are base 2. And $(2^k)^{\log d}$ is ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Eq(10.113) we can work out the size a simulating circuit must be to achieve the desired accuracy of $\epsilon/p(n)$. Rearranging Eq(10.113),
we see $1/(cp)^{2^k} = p(n)/c\epsilon$.
Taking the logarithm (base 2, as per @ChrisD) of both sides and rearranging
\begin{equation}
    2^k = \frac{\log(p(n)/c\epsilon)}{\log(1/cp)}
\end{equation}
Raising both sides to the power $\log(d)$ and noting $(2^k)^{\log{d}} = d^k$ (as per @ChrisD, again),
we can express the size of our circuit as
\begin{equation}
    d^k = \left(\frac{\log\left(p(n)/c\epsilon\right)}{\log\left(1/pc\right)}\right)^{\log{d}}
\end{equation}
The expression for $d^k$ suggests that the size of the simulating circuit scales as
\begin{equation}
    O\left(\text{poly}(\log p(n)/\epsilon)\right)
\end{equation}
i.e. the size of the circuit grows no faster than some polynomial function of $\log p(n)/\epsilon$.